# res.redirected returning false even when the backend returns a redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a login page which redirects the user back to the home page after successful login using nodejs and fetch.
Here is the code of backend.

```
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>
{
    user.findOne(req.body,(err,info)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            res.json(`error in finding item in database ,error info ${err}`);
        }

        else if(!info) 
        {
            console.log('user doesnot exist');
            let message='*please enter a valid username and password';
            res.json(message);
        }

        else{
            console.log(info);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

});
```

This is the front end code

```
form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
  
    const username=document.getElementById('username').value.trim();
    const password=document.getElementById('password').value;


    fetch('/login',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        redirect:"manual",
        body:JSON.stringify({username,password})
    }).then((res)=>{
        if(res.redirected)
        {
            console.log(`redirected to ${res.url}`);
            window.location.href=res.url;
            // return;
        }
        else{
            console.log("no")
            return res.json()
        }
    })
    .then((data)=>{
        if(data)
        alt.innerText=data;//showing the error on the page
    })
    .catch((err)=>{throw err})
})
```

When I enter the correct credentials it prints the info on the console, that means it is inside the **else** and ideally should redirect back to the home page. But it never enters the **if(res.redirected)** statement which means it is returning false.

Comment: did you trying `console.log(res.redirected)` value and what value it returns..?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes, it returns false

Comment: then it will never get called. see my solution for a better way. Usually its better not to use redirected in your way, because, you may face unexpected results. e.g if you call `http://example.com` and it redirects to `https://example.com` you get redirected as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some older chrome version does not read `res.redirected`, and for the sake of achieving cleaner codes as well as unexpected redirects (e.g. HTTP to HTTPS), you may want to set `res.direct('/')` to `res.json({ redirect: '/' })` instead.

```
const results = await fetch(....).then(res.json());

if (results.redirect) {
     window.location.href = results.redirect
}

if (results.data) {
     //do something
}
```

Backend

```
if (info) {
   return res.json({ data: info });
} else {
   return res.json({ redirect: '/', error: true })
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details on what `error:true` does?

Comment: Just demostrating how you can let front end know there's an error. You can ignore it if you want. Else, you can check `result.error`, if it's true, display an error message.